# Trouble Compiling Cilk Plus Program

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cilk-plus

I am running into trouble while trying to complie my Cilk Plus program. Basically when I run: `g++ -o reducer reducer.cpp` , I get the following error:

```
-fcilkplus must be enabled to use '_Cilk_for'
```

I've included `cilk/cilk.h` & `cilk/reducer.h`, but I am not sure what exactly is causing this problem. The code represents a simple custom reducer, nothing special. Here is how the loop looks where error occurs:

```
cilk_for(unsigned int i = 0; i<5 ; i++){

    //code

}
```

Note: I even tried using `_Cilk_for`, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add enabling the cilk plus , and linking to the library, to your build.

Your build should be:

```
g++ -fcilkplus -lcilkrts -o reducer reducer.cpp
```

For further reference see [Intel documentation](https://www.cilkplus.org/build-gcc-cilkplus)